# Keep variable tree within Watch side panel of Firebug expanded?

Tags: debugging, variables, firebug

I'm trying to use Firebug to debug my code. Under `window` it shows all the global variables, however I need to expand it every time I press the *Step Into* button. How can I leave `window` expanded at all steps?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you are talking about the variables within the [*Watch* side panel](https://getfirebug.com/wiki/index.php/Watch_Side_Panel).

If you want to observe specific variables, you can create watch expressions within that panel. To do so, just click the field saying *New watch expression...*, then enter the variable you want to watch. E.g. if you want to observe property `b` of object `a` within the global scope, you have to write `a.b`. For the first item in array `z` you simply write `z[0]`. Then hit <kbd>Enter</kbd> and the variable appears at the top of the *Watch* side panel.

In case you want to watch a whole object with all its properties you can also switch to the [*DOM* panel](https://getfirebug.com/wiki/index.php/DOM_Panel) and expand the object there, because the *Watch* side panel always collapses automatically with every debugging step.